# kodi change settings through python

Tags: python, xbmc, kodi

In Kodi, how can I change the settings level to **expert** via python code?

I managed to change all configuration through an RPC to **'Settings.SetSettingValue'** but using the same method with **'general.settinglevel'** results with an error `CSettingsManager: requested setting (general.settinglevel) was not found.`

Comment: what is the exact RPC call you have tried?

Comment: You have to change from skin settings, there is no rpc call for changing settings level to expert

Comment: well you can try changing xml settings for skin but to apply your new setting you might need to restart kodi